# How do I animate an individual UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to set animation to each cell of tableview. So if I select a cell of a table, then only just the cell will scales and seem like as flipOver animation.

I have some codes. But if i select it then, all of the table is flipovered. Not only a cell.

Here, code is following.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath : YES ];
    [UIView transitionFromView:cell toView:checkProjectView duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

How can i implement it?

And i have 2 views at this sample.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one alternate solution which you can try. While creating cell create a UIView object. The appearance of that view should be like your cell's appearance. Now set the Cell's contentview with that view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // See if there's an existing cell we can reuse
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // No cell to reuse => create a new one
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foobar"] autorelease];

    }

    // Customize cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:customView]; // customView is your view which you want to set

    return cell;
}
```

Now use your animation code for this CustomView.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath : YES ];
    [UIView transitionFromView:[cell.contentView viewWithTag:#tagof view here] toView:checkProjectView duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```