# UITableViewCell flipping animation issue (Grouped style)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859254/how-do-i-animate-an-individual-uitableviewcell) to do a flip animation on my cell in the tableview which is of grouped style. Now the issue I'm facing is this. The flip animation works. But both the margins around the cell (this is a grouped table) also flip with the cell itself.

I just want the cell to flip and the margins to stay there without interfering in the animation. What am I missing here?

The animation code from the link is as follows:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath : YES ];
    [UIView transitionFromView:[cell.contentView viewWithTag:#tagof view here] toView:checkProjectView duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add all the views that you have in the cel's contentView into a `containerView`, and the `containerView` should be added to the cell's `contentView` and use that `containerView` for the transition.

This is the best way to do it because `transitionFromView` method will replace the `fromView` with the `toView` in the view hierarchy so you will end up changing the cell`s`contentView`with your`toView`if you use cell's`contentView`as the`fromView`.